# I'm using onclick functionality inside a loop. How do I store the value of it?

Tags: javascript, loops, onclick

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  str = [str, "<div class='c3lMenuGroup padXLLeft marLTop'  width='20%'>"].join("");
  str = [str, "<input class=' wColor' name='inputId' id='inputId' onclick='c3lshow:cont_btn_" + i + "& c3lhide:cont_btn_" + k + "' align='right' width='100%' type='radio'  valign='middle'>.</input>"].join("");
  str = [str, "</div>"].join("");
}
```

I'm creating a multi-card interface where when you select one card, a continue button pops below it, and the same button hides for the other card (in case you selected a card previously). I want to use the value of 'i' of the previous card as the new value of 'k'.

Comment: Your `onclick` attributes don't actually do anything. Are `c3lshow` and `c3lhide` functions that you want to call? You need `()` around the argument, not `:` before it.

Comment: `i-1` is the value of `i` from the previous card, so `let k = i-1`

Comment: Can you provide the click event code. The above for loop code does not have any difference for div. All div will have the same div attribute ID and function.

Comment: @Barmar sir c3lshow and c3lhide are predefined functions which will show or hide the div with that id and it's working as well. I cannot use the value i-1 since you can select the 3rd card after selecting the 9th card (just an example) which means that 'k' is independent of the loop

Comment: I see, you mean the previous one clicked, not the previous one in the loop. In that case, set a global variable to the card number when you click, and use that in the next click.

Comment: @Mano here cont_btn_"+i+" is the name of the ID of the div I want to show/hide. If I click on the 3rd card, it will show the div with id "cont_btn_3". After this if I click on the 6th card, it will show the div with id "cont_btn_6" but at the same time I want to hide the previously called div i.e. "cont_btn_3". Which is why I want to store the value of 'i' in my code. Apologies for the vagueness of my question.

Comment: @Barmar how do I assign a value to it when clicked?

Comment: In the function, do `last_index = arg` where `arg` is the name of the function parameter that gets the ID that was clicked.

Comment: For that case, You can get the previously selected card value in the current or new card select event using the attribute has show. Then you use the ID to hide the previously selected.